# How can I call a global function with call_user_func?

Tags: php

The following calls a class method correctly:

```
call_user_func(array($classname, $name), $params);
```

But this does not work for a global function. How can I call a global function with `call_user_func`?

Comment: `call_user_func('function_name', $params)` - no array

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func.php)

```
function globalFunction($value)
{
    echo $value;
}


call_user_func('globalFunction', "Value");
```

If you want to call a function in the current namespace:

```
call_user_func(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\globalFunction');
```

You should declare the function before you call it with `call_user_func`.